# Math.max.apply(null, arr);

Tags: javascript, arrays

How does

```
Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

exactly work?

Suppose

```
var arr = [45,25,4,65] ;
```

will it compare 'null' and '45' and return maximum number between two adjacent e.g. 45?

After comparing will it again compare returned number and next array number e.g. 25 and return the max number?

And how is the calculation done internally? It is the same way, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of apply is what will be `this` for the function.
Here it does not matter as this function does not necessit a specific `this` value. It could matter in some other cases for instance:

```
var foo = {
    b: true,
    func: function() {
        return this.b;
    }
};
var bar = { b : false }; 

foo.func(); // true
foo.func.apply(bar); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's equal to

```
 Math.max(...arr);
```

and that's equal to:

```
 Math.max(45, 25, 4, 65);
```

How it works internally is then up to the browsers / parsers native implementation. In js it might be:

```
 Math.max = (...args) => {
   let max = - Infinity;
   for(const number of args) 
      if(number > max) max = number;
   return max;
};
```

Comment: I really love downvotes, but they are even better if they come with an explanation...